# Валидация Hashmap с помощью Json schema, возможно?

Tags: java, json, java-hashmap

Есть уже заполненный объект Hashmap, внутри другие Hashmap либо ArrayList, грубо говоря json.
Возможно ли провалидировать поля данного Hashmap  с помощью json-schema? В JS очень часто использовал данную либу, очень хотелось бы и в Java иметь такую возможность.

Comment: Возможно есть другой хороший способ проверить, что все поля пришли и они соответствуют заданным критериям, кроме как реализация в кучу if-ов

Comment: Hashmap конвертировать в json и проверить json-схемой. Может быть какая-нибудь библиотека json сможет это сделать без конвертации. Вроде jackson умеет что-то делать без лишних преобразований, но что именно не помню.